# How to get the last letter of a string?

Tags: oracle

How can I get the last letter of a string and check if it's vowel or consonant? I am using oracle 10g.

Here is what I came up with already:

```
SELECT last_name,
       Substr(last_name, -1, 1) "Last letter",
       Substr(last_name, 1, 1)  "First letter",
       CASE
         WHEN Substr(last_name, -1, 1) IN ( 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' ) THEN
         'ends with a vowel'
         WHEN Substr(last_name, -1, 1) IN ( 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f',
                                            'g', 'h', 'j', 'k',
                                            'l', 'm', 'n', 'p',
                                            'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                                            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ) THEN
         'ends with a consonant'
       END                      "Last Letter Description",
       CASE
         WHEN Substr(last_name, 1, 1) IN ( 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' ) THEN
         'starts with a consonant'
         WHEN Substr(last_name, 1, 1) IN ( 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f',
                                           'g', 'h', 'j', 'k',
                                           'l', 'm', 'n', 'p',
                                           'q', 'r', 's', 't',
                                           'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ) THEN
         'starts with a consonant'
       END                      "First Letter Description"
FROM   employees
GROUP  BY first_name,
          last_name
```

Now when you execute this on oracle 10g the "First Letter Description" is empty! What is wrong with my code?

Comment: check oracle functions substr and regexp

Comment: In SQL? PL/SQL? Do you expect a boolean result? What if the last letter is 'Y'?

Comment: I am trying to do it in oracle

Answer (score 14):

Try this, not complete, but with easy adjustments you can make it work the way you want:

```
 FUNCTION last_is_vowel (string_in VARCHAR2)
     RETURN BOOLEAN
 IS
 BEGIN
     RETURN CASE WHEN LOWER(SUBSTR(string_in, -1)) IN ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
                THEN TRUE
                ELSE FALSE
            END;
 END last_is_vowel;
```

Comment: can you make this simpler? I need to retrieve data from employees table so this is a bit complicated for me.

Comment: @DwayneRadar I'm not sure how much simpler you can get than a single CASE statement...

Comment: I agree with lc. I can't make it much simpler than that.
This function tests the last character of the string and checks if it is either 'a','e','i','o' or 'u'.
You must build a wrapper over this function if you want to use it in SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Look at your data. Chances are the first character in employees.last_name is capitalized. Remember, Oracle is case sensitive. You can user UPPER() or LOWER() to help find your match.

Also it'd be more efficient to search just for vowels and use an else statement for to find exclusions as João suggests.

```
SELECT last_name,
       Substr(last_name, -1, 1) "Last character",
       Substr(last_name, 1, 1)  "First character",
       CASE
         WHEN lower(Substr(last_name, -1, 1)) IN ( 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' ) THEN
         'ends with a vowel'
         ELSE
         'does not end with a vowel'
       END                      "Last Letter Description",
       CASE
         WHEN lower(Substr(last_name, 1, 1)) IN ( 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' ) THEN
         'starts with a vowel'
         ELSE 
         'does not start with a vowel'
       END                      "First Letter Description"
FROM   employees
GROUP  BY first_name,
          last_name
```